# Performance issue in copying VO records. in JDeveloper and ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

JDev 12c.

I am having one Master table and one child table. i have used association to derive master child relationship. I am have business requirement where i have to copy the master record as it as.

once Master row will be copy then all child record with that key will be copied in another new row.

I am able to achieve this functionality.

but  the issue is whenever i have more then 3000 records in child table its taking more then 2 minutes to copy child records.

can anyone please suggest me how can i improve the performance of this issue.

Comment: You should consider writing a procedure in this case. Modifying such huge amount of data from within VO will have performance issues

Comment: Hi Sam, I already tried to plsql approach to to copy bulk data. But the issue is I am modifying the primary key attribute.

Comment: It's working for first time when I am triggering save operation but when I click save operation twice its throwing unique Key violation exception. Please help me to solve this problem . I am stuck in this problem since 1 month.